# How to select all elements with specified css class in html using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets assume that I have retrieved page html using `HttpWebRequest` & `StreamReader`. Now I would like to cut one div from the loaded html and put it in literal on my asp.net page. I know that that div has css class content. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi, what about a regex looking for class='myclassname' ?

Comment: Regex is my last resort ;) I was hoping for more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use HtmlAgilityPack
2. Use XPath to select the node something like this

   HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='myClassName']");
3. Put the extracted node string in your page where you want.

Comment: I extracted nodes using HtmlAgilityPack & put it on page on LiteralControl. It worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try a HTML Parser for that.
Such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Then you can query as you wish.